# how does macro to get base address register from kernel works

Tags: c, kernel

I am trying to understand working of pci_resource_start function
So I browsed code via cscope and searched for string pci_resource_start
and got following in pci.h

```
 #define pci_resource_start(dev, bar)    ((dev)->resource[(bar)].start)
```

I am not able to understand how does this above macro works.
How does it above macro gets appropriate base address register in
configuration space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The macro's purpose is merely to improve readability in source code, it does not cause any address to be retrieved. In fact, the address (denoted by the `start` member) has already been discovered earlier on when the PCI bus and/or device was scanned/initialized. ("Start" in this case also means "start of address range" rather than "begin doing something".)
Details of this are most likely to be found in one of the files named `pci.c`.